# How to pipe out the results of "java -version" from DOS cmd to a text file

Tags: windows, command-line, java

I am looking for a way to put the results of "java-version" run in cmd (windows) to a text file.
I think the problem is the space between java and -version, I have tried with other commands like dir and I am able to see the output in the test file.

I also have tried using "s and nothing. I start to think it might be a constraint from Java...
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This java commands output does NOT go to the "stdout" stream (with you can re-direct with ">") but it goes to "stderr".
In order to re-direct that in a file you will need to use "2>":

```
java -version 2> outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Tonny, thank you very much, this worked I was missing the number "2", thanks!